# How to join two curves points of same index with edges using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to join points with same indices on two curves with lines to get result as shown with GPencil on screenshot, but at best I figured out how to get this mess [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you would actually only need to capture the index of the points with `Capture Attribute`, so that you can use this as a reference for `Sample Index`.

[image]

You can also capture this value in the instances after instantiation, but in some form you need a single numerical value per instantiated curve, since you want to access the points of another object.

---

And here's another solution that leads to the same goal, but is structurally quite different.

[image]

Instead of instantiating lines at the curve points, I simply duplicate a line and move its points either to the points of one circle, or to those of the other.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture points index before instancing and use it for Sample index, because instanced curve lines will have twice as points in total so indices won't match

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To produce such geometry, consider starting with a cone with one loopcut and middle tip vertex removed:

[image]

It even outputs a UV Map, but to control the inner radius you would need to select it and then scale like so:

[image]

Finally to just connect arbitrary vertices:

[image]

And of course you can use "Delete Geometry" node in "face" and "only faces" modes to delete all faces:

[image]

Well OK, still not the same, because of the rings, in such case you can easily spawn edges by extruding some verts:

[image]